# Cannot build Racket 7.9 on Big Sur

Tags: xcode, macos, racket, macos-big-sur

Racket 7.9 seg faults when starting DrRacket for the built versions.

The operating system is macos Big Sur on the Apple M1.

I tried downloading the source and rebuilding, but I get an error during the make phase.

`Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make cstartup_`./racketcgc -cu ./src/startup-select.rkt `echo "Bad startup choice, probably an error running startup-select.rkt" Bad startup choice, probably an error running startup-select.rkt exit 1`

Comment: You might want to post this on the [`racket-users`](https://groups.google.com/g/racket-users) mailing list since it's a possible bug report. You'd probably get a speedy followup there.

Comment: I posted to the racket-users group.

Comment: There's an active discussion at https://github.com/racket/racket/issues/3513. As of writing this, Racket BC can run some simple Racket programs.